# how to redefine \href to \htmladdnormallink when in \htmlonly?

Tags: hyperref, environments, latex2html

I use Scientific word (SW), which generates Latex, then I process the Latex output using Latex2html (l2h) to generate HTML as the support for HTML is better with l2h than SW (table of contents, break the page into sub pages, etc...)

SW supports the package `hyperref` but l2h does not.

Hence, when when a hyperlink is added using SW, the code generated reads like this:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{hyperref}%
\begin{document}
\href{http://www.yahoo.com}{yahoo}
\end{document}
```

The above can't be processed as is by l2h. To process this with l2h this line

```
\href{http://www.yahoo.com}{yahoo}
```

needs to change to one that l2h will process, which is

```
\htmladdnormallink{yahoo}{http://www.yahoo.com}
```

So I think all what is needed is to make `renewcommand` or similar (I am not a Latex expert). So that I would write

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{hyperref}%

\begin{htmlonly}
  write something here to make \href{a}{b} below mean \htmladdnormallink{b}{a}
\end{htmlonly}

\begin{document}
\href{http://www.yahoo.com}{yahoo}
\end{document}
```

I do not know if the above makes sense. or possible. without this, I'd have to find a way to parse the latex file each time and change each `\href` to `\htmladdnormallink` (may be I can learn `sed` or such to do it. But if there is a way to do with Latex macro that will be better.

**question is**: If the above is possible, what will the correct syntax of this command to add at the top ?

**FYI**

For completion, this is the final setup so that links work both in SW and l2h

```
 \documentclass{article}%
 \usepackage{html}  %    for L2H
 \usepackage{hyperref}%  for latex
\begin{document}

\begin{htmlonly}
  \def\href#1#2{\htmladdnormallink{#2}{#1}}  %for L2H only
\end{htmlonly}

\href{http://www.yahoo.com}{yahoo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{html}
\usepackage{hyperref}%

\begin{document}
\ifpdf\else
  \def\href#1#2{\htmladdnormallink{#2}{#1}}
\fi

\href{http://www.yahoo.com}{yahoo}
\end{document}
```

with `\ifpdf\else ... \fi` you can define code which is only used when running anything else than pdflatex.

Comment: I am missing the point of the answer actually. How is the above going to change `\href` to `\htmladdnormallink` everywhere? I do not want to edit the latex file and manually add different code for html vs. latex each time I add a link. I work in SW all the time, and just run l2h to generate HTML.  I wanted a way to do this once, at the top, using a macro, which will refdefine all the `href` to `\htmladdnormallink` everywhere only when run by l2h. i.e. I needed a switch type logic added in one place only. Thanks.

Comment: see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that is what I was looking for. Sorry that I did not understand your earlier answer, as I did not see what to write there.  btw, l2h does NOT support `\ifpdf` and `\else` and all that. But it was easy to just put the `\def` command inside `\begin{htmlonly}` and it worked. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Nasser: I know that, but that is not important because it should _not_ be used when running `pdflatex` and used with `latex2html` which is true.